# OpenShift :: how to skip the application from starting when using "oc new-app"

Tags: openshift, cloud-foundry, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

I am using openshift command `oc new-app <git-url> [OPTIONS..]` to add a new application into the openshift project.

As part of the process, it creates :

- build config & starts the build
- image stream
- replication controller
- deploy config & deploys the application

I do not intend to deploy the application instantly.

Is there a way to skip application from starting up a pod in Openshift, similar to `cf push --no-start` (in PCF)

Comment: Look at ``oc set triggers`` and disable the image change trigger. You can then enable the image change trigger later, or force a new rollout somehow using the newer image.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to build the app but not deploy it, why not consider using `oc new-build`, see also the [docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html#build-and-deployment-cli-operations) or have a look at this [example](http://v1.uncontained.io/playbooks/app_dev/binary_deployment_howto.html#creating-the-build).